# Contours generated in Leaflet losing coordinates?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, contour, d3

I am attempting to use a JavaScript library to generate contours in a leaflet map from a point layer on the map.  I have tried this approach with d3 and turf and am getting the same issue where the output contours (either polygons or polylines) have the appropriate Z value, however the coordinates are not populated:

[image]

This is my code for using the d3 library:

```
m.eachLayer(function(layer){
    if (typeof (layer.options.name) != "undefined") {
        if (layer.options.name == $('#ContourLayer').val()) {
            arr = layer.toGeoJSON().features

            console.log(collection)                             
            bounds = L.geoJson(layer.toGeoJSON()).getBounds()        
        }
    }
});

console.log(bounds)

var width = m.latLngToLayerPoint(bounds.getNorthEast()).x- 
m.latLngToLayerPoint(bounds.getSouthWest()).x  //Math.abs(Math.abs(bbox[0])- 
Math.abs(bbox[2]))
var height = m.latLngToLayerPoint(bounds.getNorthEast()).y- 
m.latLngToLayerPoint(bounds.getSouthWest()).y //Math.abs(Math.abs(bbox[1])- 
Math.abs(bbox[3]))
console.log([Math.abs(width), Math.abs(height)])

var contour = d3.contours()
.size([Math.abs(width), Math.abs(height)]);
var contoursGeoData;


contour.thresholds(breaks);

contoursGeoData = contour(arr);  

console.log(contoursGeoData)
```

I did the same process with the isolines function in the TurfJS library and got the same output (just polylines instead of polygons).  What am I doing wrong?

Also, my data (and map) are all in WGS84 (EPSG:4326).  Does the data and map have to be projected for the contours to draw?

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on without knowing how your data (specifically `arr`) looks like. It's possible that `d3.contour` is splitting the breaks properly but the data points are an empty set.

Comment: I will update the question with an example of redacted JSON data.  Thank you

Comment: [{"type": "Feature","id": "GWElevationReport.fid-27ef535b_16f163bf716_-4332","geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-000000,000000]},"geometry_name": "geometry","properties": {"facility_code": "000000","facility_name": "000000","well_id": "000000","top_casing_elev": 9999999,"measurement_date": "0000-00-00T00:00:00Z","water_level_depth": 0,"lnapl_depth": null,"lnapl_cas_rn": null,"reportable_yn": "Y","specific_gravity": null,"x_coord": "-0000000","y_coord": "00000000","elev": "0000","ProdThickness": null,"GWElevation": 0,"group_code": "0000000"}}, ... ]

Comment: I couldn't update the questions so I posted the redacted JSON example as a comment. Thanks for your input!